# Rinsing specialty grain bag after steeping

Tags: process, steeping, specialty-grains

Is there any reason to rinse the bag of specialty grains after steeping? I did this yesterday on a whim, thinking I would be able to extract as much of the sugars as possible. I used about 1qt. of hot'ish water directly into the brewpot and it seemed to work fine. At this point, I'm questioning my method since the water was not 170 degrees like the rest of the wort in the brewpot, but I guess it's a learning process.

So, should I take the time to rinse the specialty grains in the future? If so, should the water be the same temperature of the wort to be effective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used to do this.  Can't say that it really hurt or helped. I eventually started to just put the bag in an empty pot and started my boil in the main pot.  Then I'd add whatever came out of the bag into the boil later when I got around to it after the boil had gotten started.

And unless there is base malt in the bag with your specialty grains its not a mash really.  Just steeping.

Comment: If the question was worth the time to answer, wasn't it worth an upvote?

Comment: No because you aren't mashing and its not batch sparging. I didn't upvote for that reason.

Comment: Updated question to remove references to sparging and mash.

Answer (score 1):

As an all-grain BIAB guy I dump my bag in a bucket with an upside down colander.  I suppose you could do the same for a steeping bag in a small pot using the same method.